# IOS Alternate Icon does not work on Recently Used Apps

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I used this package [CLICK](https://github.com/alexaubry/alternate-icons) because I wanted to be able to create the icons through normal way which is by creating a icons catalog (Assets folder -> App Icons & Launch Images -> New iOS App Icon

I added the exact same files from my original icon catalog (same sizes, same names)

I set the alternate icon and it works, I have the new Icon. I have it on homescreen, on settings, in the notifications, on siri app suggestions EXCEPT for the icon that shows up on Recently Used Apps (double click home button or swipe up from the bottom for newer iphones)

Code for setting the icon:

```
UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("AppIconDark") { error in
    if let error = error {
        self.log(str: "SETTING ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        self.defaults.set("dark", forKey: defaultsKeys.app_icon)
        self.app_icon = "dark"
        self.log(str: "SETTING SUCCESS")
    }
}
```

At this point I'm kind of lost

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Go to Xcode -> File -> Workspace Settings

[image: Xcode > File > Workspace Settings]

2. Click DerivedData location

[image: Click DerivedData location]

3. Delete all files in DerivedData folder
4. Delete app
5. Re-install app